# nested to nested elasticsearch query with must_not not working in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, elasticsearch, indexing

I am using this gems for elastic search:

```
gem 'elasticsearch-model', '0.1.9'
gem 'elasticsearch-rails', '0.1.9'
```

I do have model A with field name id, name, price

Model B with a_id, name, size

Model C with b_id, name, rating("Low", "High").

In model A, I have added indexing like this:

```
def as_indexed_json(options={})
  as_json(
    only: [
        :id, :name, :price
      ],
      include: {:b => [include: [:c => {only: [:rating]} ]}
  )
end
```

*I want such record who **don't** have "High" rating*

I have written this method in the controller but it is not working properly.

```
A.search(query: 
           bool:{
             must_not: [
               {
                 nested: {
                   path: "b",
                   query: {
                      bool: {
                        must: [
                          {
                            term" => {
                              "b.c.rating" => "High"
                            }
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                 }
               }
             ]
           }
         ).results
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: We don't know what "working properly" means. Can you explain the error your getting?

Comment: Right now nothing works properly. Maybe need to update controller's this query as a result.